# How can perform animation when notify the gridview adapter in android

Tags: android

I'm developing grid view drag and drop.I want to rearrange grid view by using drag and drop.the mean time i want to notify the adapter and the perform some animations..
Thank You

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: grid view drag and drop. When drag and drop happen notify the adapter and perform some good animation